# Show spinner options only after fecthing data from web

Tags: android, spinner

How to show spinner options only after fetching it's to-be items from the web?

If the user touches the spinner, I want to first fetch the data from the web, parse it and set as the spinner items. The fetching / parsing works well, but the problem is that the spinner options show up too soon. I want it to only appear **after** the data's been fetched.

So, **in short**, I'd like a way to prevent the spinner from popping up until the list is fetched from the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of tryharding, i finnaly did it.

Here's the result:

```
mySpinner.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            boolean shouldHide = false;
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                shouldHide = someBooleanMethod();
            }

            return shouldHide;
        }
    });
```

and

```
private boolean someBooleanMethod(){
        if(pseudoSpinnerItemCount == 1){
            //doStuff
            return true;
        }else{
            // let the user select an option
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In the android.developer

> View.OnTouchListener

calls  'onTouch' and

> Returns
>   True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.

With this info, I just had to create some code that returns false if i want the items to be shown and true otherwise.

For some reason i feel that this should not be used like this, but it worked exactly as i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard as you think. When ever you start your login activity make your spinner empty & again populate it in onPostExecute method of AsyncTask.

That's it.

Comment: That's how it works on the first time the user is trying to login. But as i'd like to make it flow, i don't want him to wait every time for internet data, cause changing the spinner's item is kinda an exception, it should happen only once in a while (maybe months). Anyway, thks for the answer.